# java referencing

Tags: java, reference

My question is about the behind the scenes referencing :)

So I was trying to write a recursive implementation to find all the permutations of a given ArrayList (getPermsOfMe). I wrote LOOK HERE at the two specific lines i am asking about. I added thisPerm to allPermutations and then changed thisPerm later on in the code which then changed the previously added value in allPermutations to the new value.

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> allPermsHelper(ArrayList<Integer> getPermsOfMe, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> allPermutations, ArrayList<Integer> thisPerm){
    if (getPermsOfMe.isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("thisPerm = " + thisPerm);
        allPermutations.add(thisPerm); //LOOK HERE
        System.out.println("allPermutations = " +allPermutations);
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i<ofMe.size(); i++){

            //swapping the two specified elements in getPermsOfMe
            x = getPermsOfMe.get(i);
            getPermsOfMe.set(i, getPermsOfMe.get(getPermsOfMe.size()-1));
            getPermsOfMe.set(getPermsOfMe.size()-1, x);

            if (thisPerm.isEmpty()){
                thisPerm.add(getPermsOfMe.remove(getPermsOfMe.size()-1));
            }
            else{
                thisPerm.add(0,getPermsOfMe.remove(getPermsOfMe.size()-1));
            }

            allPermsHelper(getPermsOfMe, allPermutations, thisPerm);  
            getPermsOfMe.add(0,thisPerm.remove(0)); // LOOK HERE
        }
    } 
    return allPermutations;
}

//an example output (if getPermsOfMe was [123]):
thisPerm = [123]
allPermutations = [[123]]
thisPerm = [231]
allPermutations = [[231],[231]]
thisPerm = [321]
allPermutations = [[321],[321],[321]]
...
```

myQuestion is why exactly (in terms of objects and references) does the previous value not remain unchanged once it is added. So first i added [123]. next i added [231] but then allPermuations was [[231][231]] instead of [[123][231]].

Also, it seems a bit counterintuitive to me that the value wont hold once you add it. Is there a reason why Java (and im assuming some other languages) did it like this?

This is my first time asking on stackoverflow so if there is something I should do to make my question easier or whatever let me know.

Comment: If you know it's not correct and you know how to fix it, then why don't you fix it?

Comment: I did fix it.  I am trying to understand the theoretical side.

Comment: "why exactly (in terms of objects and references) does the previously added value not hold?" What do you mean by 'hold'?

Comment: Um... you wrote "Note: I know this code is not correct and I know how to fix it." in your question. Remove that then. If it's fixed, don't say it's not fixed. :P

Comment: ok i will change it. Alex, I mean why does the previous value not remain unchanged once it is added. So first i added [123]. next i added [231] but then allPermuations was [[231][231]] instead of [[123][231]]. thanks for helping!

Comment: @user1798808 Could you edit your could and rename your variables? Not sure what ofMe is supposed to be

Comment: @AlexColeman ok just did. ofMe is now getPermsOfMe. so if getPermsOfMe was [123] it should return [[123],[231],[321],[132],[213],[312]]. But I am asking about the referencing connection. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I understand now :) Here's some better example code:

```
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> listOfList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    list.add(13);
    list.add(42);
    listOfList.add(list);
    System.out.println("list = " + list);
    System.out.println("listOfList = " + listOfList);

    list1.add(46);
    System.out.println("list = " + list);
    System.out.println("listOfList = " + listOfList);
```

Has the output:

```
list = [13, 42]
listOfList = [[13, 42]]
list = [13, 42, 46]
listOfList = [[13, 42, 46]]
```

And you're expecting it to be:

```
list = [13, 42]
listOfList = [[13, 42]]
list = [13, 42, 46]
listOfList = [[13, 42]]
```

The thing is, in Java, lists are a collection of objects (or possibly primitives, but in this case we're focusing on the list of lists, which is a list of objects). Objects contain modifiable data. If we have a list of students in a high school, and we change of the students, shouldn't they be changed in all lists that put them directly into it too? So Java works like that, by using memory pointers sort of behind the scenes. If you want to make a list of students for a highschool that is static, you would have to clone all of the students and then put them in your list. Similarly in Java, you would need to clone the object to make sure that it's modification does not affect the list.

Comment: wow thank you that completely cleared things up!

Comment: oh and thanks for the example code. ill post my question like that next time

Answer (score 0):

**HOW:** Behind the scenes, anything that fits in an `Object` is just a reference, and this includes lists and arrays. This is different from primitives such as `int` or `double`.

```
int primitive = 14;
int anotherPrimitive = primitive;
System.out.println(anotherPrimitive); // 14
primitive = 12;
System.out.println(anotherPrimitive); // still 14

String[] array = new String[] {"this is a string in the array"};
String[] anotherArray = array;
System.out.println(anotherArray); // ["this is a string in the array"]
array[0] = "now i've changed it";
System.out.println(anotherArray); // ["now i've changed it"]
```

It just so happens that a `ArrayList` is a type of Object, and it stores Object references. This means that if you change the object that it is pointing to, that changes in the list.

**WHY:** It doesn't make a lot of sense to copy an entire object graph automatically without the user explicitly asking. References are very cheap to store (4 or 8 bytes in memory) and very cheap to copy (often taking one processor cycle). To copy an array of 1000 `double`s every time someone typed `doubleList.add(aThousandDoubles);` might waste a lot of time and memory unnecessarily. Furthermore, maybe you don't *want* different references; perhaps you have a `List<Foo> monitoredFoos` and you would lose the ability to read changes if the `List` implementation were to copy the object every time you were to add an item to the list.

Therefore, it makes sense to have the naïve implementation to simply store references to the existing instances on `add`, and leave it to the programmer to copy the objects if and only if you want and need the objects copied.